# Unable to run make.exe on Windows 10(Mobaxterm)

Tags: gnu-make

I am unable to run **make.exe** on Windows 10 (Mobaxterm)

I'm getting the below error:

```
 make --version
C:/Users/hp/DOCUME~1/MOBAXT~1/slash/bin/make.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygguile-2.0-22.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: It looks like you have a Cygwin version of GNU make, that was compiled with Guile support (Guile is an embedded scripting language), but that you don't have that DLL on your system.  Do you want to use Cygwin?  If not you should look for a standalone build of GNU make, such as MinGW32 version etc.  If yes, then you need to install the Guile support in Cygwin.

Comment: @MadScientist I found https://chocolatey.org/packages/make to work very well. Not that I would really recommend to try to run `make` as multi-platform tool with the pathetic shells on Windows - yes, I'm looking at you, Powershell!